# Programatically add a UICollectionView in the UITableViews viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

How can i programatically add a `UICollectionView` in the `UITableView`'s `viewForHeaderInSection` ?

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UICollectionView *cell;


    return cell;
}
```

Note: I have already added the `UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate` in the `.h` file. But, i am not sure how to programatically create the `UICollectionView` . Can someone please help.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/

Comment: can you please explain what you want to show?.. im 100% sure.. that all you need is a UICollectionView.. not a UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect)];?

I don't know your class design, but maybe you can init the collection view(s) and set their delegate and datasource in viewdidload, store them in an array, and choose the collection view at the right index in viewForHeaderInSection.